# FirestoreAdminClient exportDocuments only writes rules.json file

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

For some reason, when the following scheduled function runs, it only writes a `rules.json` file to the Cloud Storage bucket, containing some of the rules in our database.

```
export const generateBackupScheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 1 days').onRun((context) => {
  return generateBackup();
});

async function generateBackup() {
  const client = new firestore.v1.FirestoreAdminClient()
  const projectId = "project-id"
  const databaseName = `projects/${projectId}/databases/(default)`

  return client.exportDocuments({
    name: databaseName,
    outputUriPrefix: `gs://${projectId}-backups`,
    collectionIds: []
  });
}
```

However, when I run this function from the [Firebase functions shell](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-shell), or [Cloud Functions section in Google Cloud,](https://cloud.google.com/functions) it runs just fine, and creates a backup of our database.

Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Hi, have you checked cloud functions or firestore logs for any messages? If there are none GCP support is able to look to additional backend logs that could provide some leads. Also it could be worth [checking](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/function-identity) the function service account to make sure it has correct permissions for firestore

Comment: I checked logs and permissions and the only error I got was `Error serializing return value: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`. I changed the frequency, from `1 days` to `24 hours` and now the data seems to be exporting, but alongside it I stil get the `rules.json` file. Is that normal?

Comment: I don't think that is normal, very weird that 1 day schedule doesn't work but 24 hours does. Maybe reaching out to [firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support) could help on this case, I don't know what could be happening.